# Turning off Asset Catalog Compiler warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode5

Is there a way to turn off the **Asset Catalog Compiler** warnings in Xcode 5?

We've got a project that needs to be shared between Xcode 6 and 5 -
every time asset catalogs are opened in v6 a 3rd image is added for super-hi resolution.

**Example:**

```
/Users/ME/Source/Projects/Stuff/Resources/Images.xcassets: The image set "arrow" has an unassigned image.
```

Xcode6 doesn't seem to care but v5 issues *"unassigned image"* warnings for each such asset.

Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: @cesarg88 see solution below - Asset Catalog Compiler warnings can be turned off in the *Build Settings*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just turn them off in the project's **Build Settings** if it's too annoying:

[image]

**Note, however:** This particular build setting will **only show up** if there's actually an asset catalog in that particular project! Kind of wonky, but at least for Xcode 5.1, 6 and 6.1 that's how it appears to work..